# How to return different Object Type based on Condition in HTTP Response (.net core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, automapper, generic-list

I have one EF Model Class, one DTO `BaseClass` and one DTO `AdminClass` which extends from `BaseClass`. I get my data from EF and use AutoMapper class to convert to appropriate object using code below.

```
public async Task<object> GetItems()
{
    object nearestItems = _dbContext.Items.ToList(); // Gets it from DBContext.Items....
    var dtoList = IsAuthenticated ? MapObject<IEnumerable<AdminClass>>(nearestItems) : MapObject<IEnumerable<BaseClass>>(nearestItems);
    return dtoList;
}

private T MapObject<T>(object obj)
{
    object convertedObject = null;
    //convertedObject = IsAuthenticated ? _mapper.Map<IList<AdminClass>>(obj) : _mapper.Map<BaseClass>(obj);
    return (T)convertedObject;
}
```

But this returns only `BaseClass` Properties when response is sent back, even though it is Authenticated and should return `AdminClass` Properties along with `BaseClass`. In order to return Appropriate Object, I have to use If/Else condition, rather **ternary** operator and have to use `AdminClassWithoutBaseClass` to return all properties. Though not ideal because I have to do some other manipulations after, but it works. However, I would like to know how can I make it work with above syntax and also if there is a neat way of writing it.

You can see sample code on [Dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UImMiv).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Lazy Loading issue. On .net Core you have to enable lazy loading of extended properties using a proxy. Here is an in depth blog post about it: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/lazy-loading

You'll need to add the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies nuget package, and enable it when you instantiate your context service.

```
services.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(options =>
    options.UseLazyLoadingProxies());
```

Comment: I don't think it has to do anything with EF or Lazy Loading to be specific. List is already cached in memory (using .net core caching) and already have data converted to appropriate type.The issue is when HTTP Response is sent back then it only returns Properties of base type.

Comment: So if you put a breakpoint in and look at what is returned from the cache before it is sent as an http response it does actually contain the values of the AdminClass?

Comment: FYI Cache is for EF List so I don't have to make Round trips to DB. And yes I do see AdminClass List here `return list;` on the Controller Action, but on Response BaseClass List.

Comment: Are you married ot the idea of using automapper? I'm able to accomplish with manual conversion. Full example is too long for a comment...

Comment: Working example of manual conversion on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/czqin2)